# I-verbo kun relativa «kiu»

Tags: infinitive

Ĉu eblas havi i-verbon en la subfrazo de relativa «kiu»? Ekzemple, ĉu la jena frazo estas gramatike ĝusta?

> Mi volas trovi iun kun kiu iri al la kinejo.

Mi scias ke simila vortumo funkcius en la angla kaj la franca, sed mi hezitas en esperanto. Mi ne scias kie serĉi en PMEG.

Se tio ne estas bona, ĉu iu havas alternativan manieron?

Comment: Mi trovis tri ekzemplojn de tia uzo en Tekstaro per la jena serĉo `\bkun kiu [a-zĥŝĝĉĵŭ]{3,}i\b` Do eble jes?

Answer (score 3):

Tiaj esprimoj estas ĝustaj.

> *Ili ne havas, kion manĝi, ili ne havas, per kio hejti la fornon.* They do not have anything to eat, they do not have anything to heat the stove with. *(Marta)*
>
> *Oni ankaŭ ne havis longan stangon, per kiu fermŝraŭbi el sekura distanco la tubon.* Neither did they have a long rod with which to screw the pipe shut from a safe distance. *(Mortula ŝipo)*

Alimaniere:

- *Mi volas trovi iun, kun kiu mi povos iri al la kinejo.*
- *Ili ne havas ion ajn manĝi, ili ne havas ion ajn, per kio ili povus hejti la forno.*
- *Oni ankaŭ ne havis longan stangon, per kiu oni povus fermŝraŭbi la tubon.*